# Oracle 11g - One Column foreign key to two other tables

Tags: oracle, database-design, foreign-key, oracle-11g

I have table `mycar(made_by)` column. Now I have two other `BMW(bm_maker)` and `Audi(audi_maker)`. Let me explain the scenario, under `mycar(made_by)` I can have values from `BMW(bm_maker)` or `Audi(audi_maker)`.

Therefore, I want to add foreign key references to both the tables `BMW(bm_maker)` and `Audi(audi_maker)`.

Comment: Your data model is not good. You shouldn't be having a table per manufacturer

Answer (score 3):

- First, you cannot have two FK on the same column.
- Second, it's totally bad design to have a table for each automaker.

What you should do is have one `AUTO_MAKER` table with the folowing columns:

```
maker_id (PK)
maker_name
others...
```

Such a table will have as many rows as automakers you decide to have in your database, one automaker for row.

Then, in the `CAR` table create a column `maker_id` with a FK to `AUTOMAKER`'S PK. Such a column could allow `NULL` in case you don't know the automaker at the moment of inserting a row in `CAR`. Or it could not allow `NULL` if you want to be strict, so forcing users to only insert cars with known and existing automakers (existing in the AUTO_MAKER table).

By the way, the question is RDBMS agnostic.